# Malformed data error when reading Confluent encoded Avro records using Spark with AWS Glue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

The problem

I'm using Spark with AWS Glue to read Confluent encoded Avro records from a kafka topic.
First, I tried using *from_avro* function of Spark, but no success because Confluent Avro encoded messages are different from what this function expects.

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1") \
  .option("subscribe", "topic") \
  .option("kafka.group.id", group_id) \
  .option("kafka.client.id", client_id) \
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", truststore) \
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", password) \
  .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", keystore) \
  .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", password) \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .option("endingOffsets", "latest") \
  .load()

output = df.select(from_avro("value", jsonFormatSchema, options={"mode":"PERMISSIVE"}).alias("data"))
```

Comment: Note: Glue has its own Registry, which is not the same as "Confluent encoding", AFAIK